# MIPS code for reading 2 integers and dividing them to get float output?

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a programme that reads 2 integers , divides them to get the output as float. Eg  2/3 = 0.66666666 . I have written the following programme .

```
.data
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter x: "
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter y: "  
floatzero: .float 0.0

.text
main:
    l.s $f4, floatzero
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt1
    syscall

    li $v0, 6
    syscall

    add.s $f12 , $f0 , $f4


    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt2
    syscall

    li $v0, 6
    syscall

    add.s $f14, $f0, $f4

    li $v0 , 2
    div.s $f16, $f12, $f14
    syscall

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Now I have the following doubts :
1. For 2/3 It is showing output is 2.0000000. What should i correct to get 0.66666666 ?

2. Is there any method I can use to directly move the input value from $v0 to     some $f2 . Here I am using add.s (which too doesent seem to work well). ?
3. Why can I not simply take input as integer , save it in integer format ( like $a1) then divide it to save the answer in float format ?

P.S. This is my homework , but I need basic concepts like this to solve it . Please help.

Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 2):

1. You're storing the quotient in `$f16`, but system call 2 expects the value to print in `$f12`.
2. `mov.s $f2, $f0`
3. You can, but you'll have to move the integer values to floating point registers and convert them to floating point values before the division. An integer division between 2 and 3 would just give you 0 as a result. Questions about how to do this conversion have already been asked several times, so google e.g. *"mips int to float"*.